# Mechanism of R-OH to R-X using SOCl2

Tags: reaction-mechanism, hybridization

https://youtu.be/ANlXQdpv6cc?t=1006

In this lecture, I am learning on the reaction of alcohol to alkyl halide using SOCl2 and pyridine. However, there are 2 different approaches on the first step.

[image]

The 1-step initial step, which is printed on many reference books.

[image]

The 2-step 'inital step' (forming the same intermediate), which the lecturer says is correct. This is because during a SN2, the sulfur (atom bonded to the leaving group - Cl) must be sp3 hybridized, otherwise, SN2 cannot happen (so figure 1 is wrong).

I have no idea why figure 1 is wrong though. Sulfur in SOCl2 is sp3 hybridized. (1 lone pair, '3' bonds), while the lecturer says the sulfur is actually **dsp3** hybridized, not sp3. So my questions are:

1. is sulfur dsp3 or sp3 hybridized?
2. Why can't SN2 reaction happen if it is not sp3 hybridized?

(3.) Which step above is the most plausible?

Comment: Hybridisation in its simplest form ("sp3/sp2/sp") starts to fall apart for non-second row elements. (Don't even think about using it for transition metals.) In any case, there should be very negligible d-orbital participation, so sp3 is probably a better description. This dsp3 thing really shouldn't be taught anymore. For mechanism of substitution see [Substitution at thionyl chloride sulfur](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/48489/16683).

Comment: So it is actually dsp3 hybridized instead of sp3? And when I encounter similiar situations later, I just need to think of s & p orbitals and ignoring others e.g. during SN2?

Comment: Quite the contrary; you shouldn't use d-orbitals to describe bonding in "hypervalent" molecules, as usually it isn't needed. When you call something "dsp3" you are basically saying that d-orbitals play a critical role in the bonding. Why did you get the impression I was saying it was "dsp3"?

Comment: Also, [this](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/12/03/reagent-friday-thionyl-chloride-socl2/) gives good overview.