# Why is chlorosulfite a good leaving group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, nucleophilic-substitution, halogenation

I came across the following website article<sup>[[1]](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/02/10/socl2-and-the-sni-mechanism/)</sup>:

[image: SNi mechanism]

I understand the mechanism and also get the fact that this is nothing but an experimental result but why does the $\ce{ClSOO-}$ group departs spontaneously to form a carbocation? Also since carbocation is formed will there be any rearrangement(if possible)?

**Reference:**

[[1]](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/02/10/socl2-and-the-sni-mechanism/): SOCl2 mechanism for alcohols to alkyl halides: SN2 versus SNi
https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/02/10/socl2-and-the-sni-mechanism/
(accessed Jun 15, 2021).

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69063/if-socl2-reacts-with-alcohols-via-sni-why-doesnt-pocl3?r=Searchresults ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48489/substitution-at-thionyl-chloride-sulfur